# How to select all articles from one category and sub-category In MySQL 5

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Three tables save articles information:

categories table:

```
id, lft, rgt, title
```

lft: left value

rgt: right value

lft and rgt value is Nested Set, example:

```
           root 
          (0,15)
          /    \
         /      \
       cat1    cat2
      (1,6)   (7, 14) 
       /|      / | \
      / |     /  |  \
     /  |    /   |   \
 cat3 cat4  cat5 cat6 cat7
(2,3) (4,5) (8,9)(10,11)(12,13)
```

article table:

```
id, title
```

article_category_map table:

```
article_id, category_id
```

How to select all articles from one category and sub-category in MySQL?

I expect:

1、When click cat2, display all articles of cat2 and cat5 and cat6 and cat7.

2、When click cat5 , only display all articles of cat5.

3、Wher click root, display all articles of all categories (include cat1, cat2, cat3,cat4, cat5, cat6, cat7...).

Comment: Whr is your subcat table, post that also. And, do you want to fetch the data for a known cat ID or you want to fetch the data based on dynamic cat ID?

Answer (score 0):

I guess 'lft' and 'rgt' stand for "left" and "right" properties of the [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree).

Suppose `$category_id` is ID of the category, `Db::fetch` method fetches single row from database, `Db::fetchAll` method fetches all rows matching an SQL query.

Then you can fetch "left" and "right" of the category, then fetch articles from the category and its subcategories.

```
if (! $cat = Db::fetch("SELECT lft, rgt
  FROM categories WHERE id = $category_id"))
{
  // handle error
}

$articles = Db::fetchAll("SELECT a.* FROM article a
  JOIN article_category_map m ON m.article_id = a.id
  JOIN categories c ON c.id = m.category_id
  WHERE c.id BETWEEN ${cat['lft']} AND {$cat['rgt']}");
```